# python3 how to set os.environ variable when its value is json object?

Tags: python-3.x, environment-variables, environment

Have tried,

```
export "INDEX_SET"="{"index_all":false,"index_group":true,"index_channel":true,"exclude_chats":[],"include_chats":[1522205730]}"
```

but received this error:

> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in
> double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
>
> Please set the INDEX_SETTINGS environment variable correctly

from the python code as:

```
index_set_str = os.environ["INDEX_SET"].strip()
index_settings = json.loads(index_settings_str)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shell quoting is wrong. Try:

```
export INDEX_SET='{"index_all":false,"index_group":true,"index_channel":true,"exclude_chats":[],"include_chats":[1522205730]}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the double quotes when exporting the environment variable.  For example:

```
export INDEX_SET="{\"index_all\":false,\"index_group\":true,\"index_channel\":true,\"exclude_chats\":[],\"include_chats\":[1522205730]}"
```

Alternatively, export it in Base64 encoding and decode it in your code.